# When to use different import types in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When Choosing File > Import... in Eclipse while working on an Android project, I'm presented with these options:

General

- Exisisting Projects into Workspace
- File System
- Existing Android Code into Workspace

Git

- Projects from Git

I'm clear about how to use "Project from Git" e.g clone from github to local, then import to workspace. But what is the correct use and usage scenario of the options under General? In particular, how is "Existing projects into Workspace" different from "Existing Android Code into Workspace"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how is "Existing projects into Workspace" different from "Existing
> Android Code into Workspace"?

1. **Import > General > Existing projects into Workspace**

   It means you want to load C++ Projects, Java, or any project which is created by Eclipse in your workspace. You can also import your **Android Projects** in this way.
2. **Import > Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace**

   You want to load only Android Projects in your workspace

**UPDATE 1:**

> But what is the correct use and usage scenario of the options under General?

You don't need to worry about it. If you're really concerned in your project inside your git repository,

I suggest to load that project through EGit (Eclipse Git). You can also load that project through "General" way but the difference is

You cannot perform managing branches, commits, commit changes, or else using EGit.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference if I import an Android project with "Existing projects" vs "Existing Android Code" ? I mean once the project is imported into the workspace and I start to work with it?

Comment: AFAIK you **can't** import Android projects with "Existing projects into Workspace"...

Comment: @PierreRymiortz I can't tell. You don't need to worry about it :)

Comment: @Ahmad I tried it with a basic Hello World project and it worked, in the sense that it showed up in the workspace with structure and files as expected. Any aspect I'm missing as to why it wouldn't work?

Comment: Hmm, sorry I tried it out once and it didn't work... Well, then no. No difference

Comment: Try to create new project in android, export it (> Export > General > Archive File). Delete the loaded project in your workspace. And try to import the project which is exported in archive file

Answer (score 2):

**Existing Projects into Workspace:**

java projects in general/or depending on your Eclipse version projects in other languages (e.g. not an Android app)

**Existing Android Code into Workspace:**

Android projekt